# How to put a specific html area on an extra page when printing it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, printing, print-css

i'm searching for a way to put the left aside-area from my website on an extra page when i'm printing it. 
May someone had the same problem and found an easy way to do that.

At the moment, my website were printing element by element, but I want to control it. I want, that a specific element were printed on the next page and not just after the element before.

Comment: have a look at print style sheets and page break css

Comment: Can you give us a sample of your code, or, at least, an example of what you'd like your page to look like? Please edit your question with these items.

Comment: I'm solve my problem! 
Thanks to Pete!

Comment: I'm using page break, to print the element on the next page.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that specifically for print using media query.

```
@media print
{
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```